# How to test my static Public function using Hydra

Tags: eosio.cdt, eosiocpp

The heading really explains it all, I am writing a smart contract for which in its header file I have defined two static public functions, which I want to test using Hydra testing library can anyone guide me in how I can do this.

Comment: Have you checked out the docs? https://docs.klevoya.com/hydra/about/getting-started/. You can see an example of a project using the framework here as well: https://github.com/pinknetworkx/atomicassets-contract-tests

Comment: I looked through the documents but wasn't able to find anything regarding testing static getter functions

Comment: Ask them in their telegram, chris should help you https://t.me/klevoya

Comment: Thankyou very much